# How do I name the results of a joined table query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables and did an inner join on them based on id. Now I need to name this joined table. How do I do that? The reason I want to name this table is because I have to join this result table with some other tables.

Comment: Can you show us your code so we can see what you're working with? Feel free to anonymize table and field names of course.

Comment: Select * from(select a.CKey,a.AKey,c.CName, c.CID,c.Status from tCuAddr a  
inner join tCustomer c on 
a.CKey=c.CKey and CID ='AAA')as P;

Comment: BUt I don see the table p in my tables list

Comment: Why do you need this? Either the new join condition is on a calculated column or a projected one there is no need to create a subquery

Answer (score 0):

You created what is commonly referred t as a *relvar*, not another table. You can join to it by placing it's SELECT definition in a sub query like this:

```
SELECT
FROM (
  -- original join SQL
) t
INNER JOIN table2 on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
    select * from TableA a join TableB b on a.id = b.a_id
) as p;
```

As per the comments, it seems that a `view` might be what you are looking for:

```
create view MyView
as
select * from TableA a join TableB b on a.id = b.a_id;
```

It won't be listed in the tables (rather in the views), but will behave just like a table in your sql editor.

Comment: Thanks . but I do not see my table name in the list of tables.

Comment: It's not a real table. Think of it as a temporary table that only exists for the duration of the query. I think what you might be looking for is a view. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias for the result of a `join` using a subquery.  For example:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        from    tbl1
        join    tbl2
        on      tbl1.id = tbl2.id
        ) as JoinAlias
join    tbl3
on      JoinAlias.id = tbl3.id
```

You can often make do without such an `alias`.  For example, consider a third join:

```
select  *
from    tbl1
join    tbl2
on      tbl1.id = tbl2.id
join    tbl3
on      tbl3.col1 = tbl1.col1
        and tbl3.col2 = tbl2.col2
```

As you can see, the third `join`'s condition can refer to columns from all earlier tables.